# Injecting service into another service does not work

Tags: 8, domain-access, symfony-services

I have to override `pagecache` service in order to have some custom validation logic to be executed for anonymous users. The issue is that I have the `domain` module's service `domain.negotiator` to be injected into `pagecache` service, but when I call the `domain.negotiator` service it is always `null` no matter what I do. I think it has to do with something with priority. I can confirm the overridden service is being executed.

Code to override **PageCache** service

```
/**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    // Overrides language_manager class to test domain language negotiation.
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('http_middleware.page_cache');
    $definition->setClass('Drupal\hcl_login\StackMiddleware\StaticCache')->addArgument(
      new Reference('domain.negotiator'),
    );
  }
```

Overridden service

```
/**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function handle(Request $request, $type = self::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = TRUE): Response {
    $domain = \Drupal::service('domain.negotiator');
    $x = $this->domainNegotiator->getActiveDomain();
    $currentDomain = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('domain')->createHostname();
    $response = parent::handle($request, $type, $catch);
    return $response;
  }
```

Comment: Even if it looks like a service, a middleware is not a Drupal service, it runs outside of the Drupal kernel.

Comment: Thanks, @4k4 for replying, Is there any workaround to achieve it. Initially, I was using subscribing to event KERNAL:: REQUEST to add the custom validation logic that needs to run on every single page for anonymous users, but because of drupal caching, Pages were cached and it was not achieveable.

Comment: Workaround for what? The page cache is like a reverse proxy caching based on the URL (including domain name and query string by the way). If this is not what you want then uninstall this module and use the dynamic page cache.

Comment: What about `$request->getHost()` or `$request->getSchemeAndHttpHost()`?

Comment: @leymannx Still, I would need user service to check which is always showing anonymous users, I tried with event subscriber but when I set the priority to 210, I can't access the service.

Comment: Another issue is that when using event subscribers, pages are being cached and custom validation is not being executed every time.